# Matching style of joints between Belgium blocks

Tags: masonry, landscaping, paving

I'm looking to lay a new section of Belgium blocks to border a new flower bed. However, the existing Belgium blocks have a joint connecting each block that protrudes outward. It is not clear to me whether this is a spacer block or perhaps mortar shaped using a jointing tool. Is there a known technique to match the style of the existing edging shown below?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That appears to be what's called a "beaded" mortar joint. It's tooled from the mortar. Tools and videos can be found by searching using that term.